# How to write a effective k8s delete job in CI

Tags: kubernetes

I've started learning k8s and I noticed that in our organization they have a jenkins job to delete resources.

The job has this following code and runs as a shell.

```
kubectl delete -o name -f $file | grep deployment | xargs kubectl rollout status --namespace=${namespace}
```

But unfortunately , this delete job always is in failed state.

```
13:05:04 + kubectl delete -o name -f services/stg/applications/stg-x/foo-svc.yml
13:05:04 + grep deployment
13:05:04 + xargs kubectl rollout status --namespace=stg-x
13:05:04 Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "stg-x-foo-svc" not found
13:05:04 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
13:05:17 Finished: FAILURE
```

Does this mean that we can't do a rollout status on a deleted deployment resource? or is entirely different issue? Looking for an effective solution that would help to check the status after a delete irrespective of what is being deleted.

Ps: This job is common for all resources, the developers just pass the file to delete particular resource. (replicasets,deployment,daemonsets,pods,stateful-sets)

Comment: As your question is written, it's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to get help with. There is no "rollout" status for a deleted `Deployment`. Does your `$file` contain multiple resources and you want to wait until they are all deleted, is that your underlying question? Are you experiencing that they are **not** being deleted right now? This question needs a great deal of focus

Comment: what output do you expect to see?

Comment: Sounds to me like you might want to consider using [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_status/) vs individual manifests. I second @mdaniel comment, there is not enough context to define the scope.